# Sum and product of 9 digits

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Adding single digits 1 to 9, the result is 45 and their product is 362880.

Are there any other 9 single digits with sum 45 and product 362880?

Comment: The only 'other' digit is 0. Clearly no set of 9 digits including 0 will give a product different from 0. If repetitions are allowed, please make that explicit.

Comment: repetition is allowed, but I consider this being part of the riddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer:

> Yes, there are.

We can

> replace 3,6,8 with 4,4,9. This will not change the sum or product.